# How to extract the number from a string in power pivot?

Tags: powerpivot

Hi i have a power pivot sheet with description column
which Values like this

```
PMS   1,500   Promo
Demo  25,000  Project
```

how can i get the number from the string?

my expected result is

```
Description              value
PMS 1,500 Promo          1,500
Demo 25,000 Project     25,000
```

im new with power pivot :(

Comment: could you upload the file?

Comment: Hey there. If this helped, you can help other users by marking the answer as correct. If not, comment here so we can get to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually the same method you would use in an Excel formula.

I did this in a formula on a sheet, but you could do the same in a Calculated Column in PowerPivot

`=VALUE(MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1,FIND(" ",A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1)-FIND(" ",A2)))`

It's a bit messy but does the job.